# What is an object's velocity with zero acceleration after positive acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

I am not 100% sure I'm understanding this graph correctly. Here are my 2 theories.

An object has constant +acceleration and is moving towards some direction.

If the object's acceleration is cut off to 0:

1) Would it mean the object is still in motion from its previous force?

 (example:   after car stops accelerating it is just rolling)

**Proof:** If so its moving at constant velocity and then `Δv = 0` so `a = Δv / Δt` will be zero ?

2) Or does it mean the object immediately stops motion?

 (example:   a car stops accelerating immediately because it brakes)

**Proof:** If so mathematically this would be velocity `V = a*t`  which is `V = 0*t` and you get `V = 0 m/s`

[image]

Comment: You need an initial velocity to answer these questions.

Comment: "An object has constant +acceleration and moving at constant velocity"  So which one is it?  Acceleration is a change in velocity.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention the initial velocity is 0. The object describes the motion of "a particle that Starts from rest." Not sure why you wanted the initial velocity though.

Comment: Acceleration is defined as the change in velocity, if the object has a positive acceleration, it is *gaining* velocity. If the object has 0 acceleration, it is maintaining a *constant* velocity.

Comment: @KieranMoynihan, so its theory #1 because the change in NON ZERO velocity is 0 and therefore (acceleration =  0 / delta t ) which will equal 0 accretion.  BUT if I solved for Velocity = a*t I would get V = 0 which means the velocity. = 0

Comment: The area under a velocity against time graph is equal to the change in velocity.

Answer (score 1):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding about the relationship between velocity and acceleration.

- Velocity is the change in distance over time ($m/s$)
- Acceleration is the change in velocity over time ($m/s^2$)

Perhaps answering the questions you posed will help you understand this relationship better:

> 1) Would it mean the object is not accelerating but still in motion from the left over force? (example; after car stops accelerating it is just rolling)
>   In this case there seems like there would be velocity just slowing down.

Yes, if acceleration dropped to $0$ the object would still be in motion, but not because of some 'left over force', because the velocity of the object would not longer be *changing*. Look back to the relationship I described above, acceleration is the *change* in velocity over time, not just the velocity over time. If acceleration is $0$, the velocity is not changing. If the velocity is constant ($0$ acceleration) then the object will continue without slowing down or speeding up.

> 2) Or does this graph describe an object who is accelerating @ 0s-10s and stopping all motion @ 10s-15s? In this case mathematically makes sense because if you solve for velocity V = a*t you get 0 m/s

The graph describes an object which is accelerating from $0s$ to $10s$, and **not accelerating** from $10s$ to $15s$. As in the last question, the fact the the object is not accelerating does not mean that the velocity is $0$, it means that the velocity remains constant at whatever value it was just before acceleration became $0$.

Additionally, $V \ne a*t$, because the relationship is not between velocity and acceleration, but **change in velocity** and acceleration. The proper formula would be $\Delta V = a*\Delta t$, where $\Delta t$ would in this case be $15s - 10s = 5s$ This would mean that $\Delta V = (0m/s^2)*(5s) = 0$, so velocity would not change, but would remain constant.

Comment: I made this answer before seeing your addition of the 'proofs' to the question, if you don't believe I have properly addressed them, I will add my answer to them soon.

Comment: " then the object will continue without slowing down or speeding up."  that is a very weird concept. I can't imagine anything natural that can move at that speed. thanks for your help.

Comment: @localplutonium Imagine a spaceship. What happens happens when you turn off the rocket engines? Does the spaceship stop? Or does it continue drifting with constant speed, since there is no force to cause acceleration/change in speed anymore?

Comment: @localplutonium bear in mind that acceleration being 0 does not mean that there are no forces acting on the object, just that all the forces cancel out. If a person driving a car down the road provides enough gas to keep the car rolling forward at a constant rate (driving at highway speeds for example), but not so much that the car is speeding up, then the car has 0 acceleration and a non-zero, constant velocity.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it mean the object is still in motion from its previous force? (example; after car stops accelerating it is just rolling)

Yes. As soon as acceleration disappears, the object just continues **with whichever speed it has**. The acceleration changes speed; is there no acceleration, then speed is constant.

Speed is how many extra metres you are moving every second. Acceleration is how many extra metres **per second** you are moving with every second. No acceleration then just means that no more metres per second are added or subtracted. The object just keeps what it has.

> Proof: If so its moving at constant velocity and then Δv = 0 so a = Δv / Δt will be zero ?

Sure.

> Or does this graph describe an object who is accelerating @ 0s-10s and stopping all motion @ 10s-15s?

Nope. That would be the case, if the *speed* was cut off to 0 suddenly.

> Proof: If so mathematically this would be velocity V = a*t which is V = 0*t and you get V = 0 m/s

True. But only *if* that was the case; which is wasn't.

Comment: okay so the velocity during 10-15 seconds is the final velocity @ 10 seconds?

Comment: @localplutonium Genau.